# TMS slider and jcarousellite plugin working in IE only

Tags: jquery, html

This is my page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<!--box slider-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jcarousellite1.0.1_min.js"></script>
<!--jquery no conflict-->//i used noconflict to use these sliders in IE
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
$(window).load(function() {
$("#slidertext").jCarouselLite({    //i used jcarousellite plugin two times,this is the first one
    btnNext: ".next",
    btnPrev: ".prev"
});
});
$(window).load(function() {     //second jcarousellite plugin
$("#slidertext2").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: ".next2",
    btnPrev: ".prev2"
});
});
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
<!--no conflict end-->
<!--banner slider-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Vegur_300.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/PT_Sans_700.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/PT_Sans_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tms-0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tms_presets.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/atooltip.jquery.js"></script>
    <!--banner slider end-->

    </head>
    <body>
```

.............

```
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('#slider')._TMS({
                banners:true,
                waitBannerAnimation:false,
                preset:'diagonalFade',
                easing:'easeOutQuad',
                pagination:true,
                duration:400,
                slideshow:8000,
                bannerShow:function(banner){
                        banner.css({marginRight:-500}).stop().animate({marginRight:0}, 600)
                },
                bannerHide:function(banner){
                    banner.stop().animate({marginRight:-500}, 600)
                }
                })
        })
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

There are 3 sliders, one image slider and two jcarousel lite plugins in my page. It is working fine in IE. But in the other browsers, only the TMS slider works. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can try using jQuery directly instead of $ to avoid conflict..well yes thats a tedious job..but you can use it as option for some small codes for noConflict.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. Just change the older jquery to New jquery available at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js

Hope, it will resolve your issue.